# Tensorflow 1.8.0 with Python 3.6.4 in Anaconda show error _dataset_ops.so not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am using tensorflow 1.8.0 in anaconda environment, when trying to run a python file it shows me the following errors:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3>python.exe clasifica.py
C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clasifica.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .variables import variable
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\variables.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import data
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.error_ops import ignore_errors
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\error_ops.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops import contrib_op_loader  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\contrib_op_loader.py", line 24, in <module>
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("../../_dataset_ops.so"))
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\util\loader.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
  File "C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: C:\Users\Jose\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\..\..\_dataset_ops.so not found
```

I am working with:

Tensorflow version: 1.8.0,
Python 3.6.4 in Anaconda,
windows 10 Pro

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error as well. If you run tensorflow on gpu then here's the pick, follow this path and locate _dataset_ops.so

D:\programfiles\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data

then move _dataset_ops.so  file out of that folder to another location.

Answer (score 0):

The [solution by Awasthi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942347/4675277) works perfectly fine. You might need to do the same for these 4 OS files as well.

> 1) NotFoundError: C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\coder\python\ops_coder_ops.so not found
>   2) NotFoundError: C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops_gru_ops.so not found
>   3) NotFoundError: C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops_lstm_ops.so not found
>   4)NotFoundError: C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\nccl\python\ops_nccl_ops.so not found